# cannot access '/opt/unityhub/chrome-sandbox': No such file or directory Error when install UnityHub

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to make automated build of my Unity project with Jenkins, and Jenkins is installed on my Linux server. So I am trying to install UnityHub on Rocky Linux 8(only CUI).

I followed [Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/hub/manual/InstallHub.html#install-hub-linux) to install UnityHub on Linux, but some error occurred.

```
$ sudo yum install unityhub
...
Running scriptlet: unityhub-3.2.0-1.x86_64                                        5/5
chmod: cannot access '/opt/unityhub/chrome-sandbox': No such file or directory
...
$ unityhub
The futex facility returned an unexpected error code.
Aborted (core dumped)
$ ls /opt/unityhub/chrome-sandbox
ls: cannot access '/opt/unityhub/chrome-samdbox': No such file or directory
```

[image]

How can I solve this? Or is there any other way to build Unity project on Linux CUI?

Answer (score 0):

After installing run:

```
sudo dnf install openssl1.1 openssl-libs
```

Hope this helps